# StreamWriter end line with Lf rather than CrLf

Tags: .net, text, streamwriter

I'm using StreamWriter to output a text file, but I would like to end my WriteLine with Lf rather than the default CrLf. Is there an easy way to do this using a parameter built into StreamWriter?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It comes with a [NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.newline.aspx) property for just that.

Answer (score 4):

Just call .write and add the line break at the end?